# How to match any value in one grouped variable with any value in another?

Tags: dplyr, grouping

I'm trying to create a new variable on which I can filter based on values being present in any row of a group in two other variables.  I've not been able to find a solution (or perhaps I've not formulated my search properly! :-/).
For example:

```
require(tidyverse)

base <- 
  tibble(
    group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
    value_A = c("a", NA_character_, "b", NA_character_,
                NA_character_, "c", NA_character_, NA_character_,
                NA_character_, "a", "c", NA_character_),
    value_B = c(NA_character_, "c", NA_character_, NA_character_,
                NA_character_, "c", "b", NA_character_,
                "a", NA_character_, NA_character_, "c")
  )

> base
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   group value_A value_B
   <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
 1 A     a       NA     
 2 A     NA      c      
 3 A     b       NA     
 4 A     NA      NA     
 5 B     NA      NA     
 6 B     c       c      
 7 B     NA      b      
 8 B     NA      NA     
 9 C     NA      a      
10 C     a       NA     
11 C     c       NA     
12 C     NA      c
```

And this is what I'm after:

```
desired_outcome <- 
  base |>  
  mutate(desired_filter = rep(c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), each = 4))

> desired_outcome
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   group value_A value_B desired_filter
   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <lgl>         
 1 A     a       NA      FALSE         
 2 A     NA      c       FALSE         
 3 A     b       NA      FALSE         
 4 A     NA      NA      FALSE         
 5 B     NA      NA      TRUE          
 6 B     c       c       TRUE          
 7 B     NA      b       TRUE          
 8 B     NA      NA      TRUE          
 9 C     NA      a       TRUE          
10 C     a       NA      TRUE          
11 C     c       NA      TRUE          
12 C     NA      c       TRUE
```

Clearly, the following won't work because any() returns a logical; however, it kind of illustrates what I want to do in layman's terms, I think.

```
base |> 
  mutate(filter = if_else(any(value_A)==any(value_B), TRUE, FALSE))
```

The following code works, but I'm not sure that it would be robust and work in all cases.  And it's pretty ugly.

```
possible_solution <- 
  base |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  mutate(value_B_new = value_B) |> 
  fill(value_B_new, .direction = "downup") |> 
  mutate(int_filter = as.numeric(value_A==value_B_new),
         filter = if_else(any(int_filter==1), 1, 0)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  replace_na(list(filter = 0)) |> 
  mutate(filter = as.logical(filter))

> possible_solution
# A tibble: 12 × 6
   group value_A value_B value_B_new int_filter filter
   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>            <dbl> <lgl> 
 1 A     a       NA      c                    0 FALSE 
 2 A     NA      c       c                   NA FALSE 
 3 A     b       NA      c                    0 FALSE 
 4 A     NA      NA      c                   NA FALSE 
 5 B     NA      NA      c                   NA TRUE  
 6 B     c       c       c                    1 TRUE  
 7 B     NA      b       b                   NA TRUE  
 8 B     NA      NA      b                   NA TRUE  
 9 C     NA      a       a                   NA TRUE  
10 C     a       NA      a                    1 TRUE  
11 C     c       NA      a                    0 TRUE  
12 C     NA      c       c                   NA TRUE
```

I'd like to avoid pivoting as I think my actual data set is too complex to be sure I don't introduce errors.
Many thanks for any help, or links to a previously answered question that's the same or close.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for? It is very unclear how you what to decide what is `TRUE` and what is `FALSE`. Add some of the code you have tried, even if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks @mfg3z0 - sorry, it's clear in my head!!! I'll edit the question shortly...

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
library(rlang)

mutate(base, c = !is_empty(intersect(value_A[!is.na(value_A)], value_B[!is.na(value_B)])), .by = group)
```

A couple of alternatives/things you could change about this:

1. if you'd prefer to not use the `rlang` library, you could swap `is_empty(foo)` for `length(foo) == 0`
2. if you'd prefer to keep things a bit tidier, you could put it all into a function, and then call that:

```
group_intersect <- function(a, b) {
      !is_empty(intersect(a[!is.na(a)], b[!is.na(b)]))
}

mutate(example, c = group_intersect(value_A, value_B))
```